# Normal Form Vector Equation for Plane Containing $A(-2,1,5)$ and $\text{Line: } (2-\mu)i+(3+\mu)j+(4+\mu)k$

Tags: vector-spaces

I am doing part (ii) of

[image]

> Find normal form equation of plane containing $A(-2,1,5)$ and $\text{Line: } (2-\mu)i+(3+\mu)j+(4+\mu)k$

I did:

$AB=4i+2j-k$

$\text{normal} = (4i+2j-k)\times(=2i+j+5k)=11i-18j+11k$

this aleary doesnt seem right. Answer is $r\cdot (i-j+2k)=7$

Comment: Take any two points on the line; with the other given point, you now have three points. You can now use the method of the previous question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the equation of the plane normal to $\bf n$ containing $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$
is
$$
{\bf n}\cdot[ (x-x_0) i +(y-y_0) j + (z-z_0)k]=0.\qquad\qquad(1)
$$

In your problem, we need to find a normal vector for the plane.

To do this, we need two independent vectors in the plane. The direction vector of the line, $-i+j+k$,  will serve as one. For the other, take the vector formed by the  difference of $A$ and any point on the line. Since the line is in the plane $B=2i+3j+4k$ will serve.
Now $AB= 4i +2j -k$ is your second  vector in the plane.

To obtain the vector normal to the plane, take the cross product of $AB$ and the direction vector   of the line.

$${\bf n}=AB\times( -i+j+k )=\Biggl|\matrix{ i&j&k\cr 4&2&-1\cr -1&1&1\cr}\Biggr|=
3 i -  3j +6k.
$$

The equation of the plane is, using (1) with $B$ as the point:
$$
{\bf n}\cdot[ (x-2) i +(y-3) j + (z-4)k]=0.
$$

---

To see that this gives the same result of the author:
$$
\eqalign{
&{\bf n}\cdot[ (x-2) i +(y-3) j + (z-4)k]=0 \cr
\iff&(3i-3j+6k)\cdot[ (x-2) i +(y-3) j + (z-4)k]=0 \cr
\iff&(3i-3j+6k)\cdot[ (x i +yj + zk) +( -2i-3j-4k)]=0 \cr
\iff&(3i-3j+6k)\cdot  (x i +yj + zk) =(3i-3j+6k)\cdot(  2i+3j+4k)  \cr
\iff&(3i-3j+6k)\cdot  (x i +yj + zk) =21  \cr
\iff&(i-j+2k)\cdot  (x i +yj + zk) =7 \cr}
$$

---

Final edit:

More simply, the author is using the vector plane equation 
$$\tag{2}{\bf n}\cdot {\bf r} ={\bf a}\cdot{\bf n}$$ where $\bf n$ is the normal vector, $\bf  r$ is the position vector to the plane and 
$\bf a$ is the position vector of a point on the plane. So, once you find $\bf n$, take ${\bf a}=2i+3j+4k$, and substitute into (2).